# How track new users through using GA4 Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Can I send via GA4 measurement protocol something event (like "first_visit") or params to my GA4 acc to appear "new users"?

Just now I only send some event name with param = "engagement_time_msec" and GA4 show "active" users. But not "new".

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the client_id value in the request to generate new users.

Comment: Not working for me. New users always 0

Comment: can we generate a random client_id ?